# Swift - Serialize object containing array of objects and send with alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i need to send post request with class as parameter using Alamofire.
My class contains array of other class and I'm stuck because of that.

```
class CreateRecordData{
    var RecordDate: String?
    var RecordType: String?
    var SubType: String?
    var Name: String?
    var MovementRecords: [RecordMovementData]?
    var MeasurementId: Int?
    var SensorType: String?
}


class RecordMovementData{
    var FrameRate: Int?
    var JointType: String?
    var Samples: [MovementSampleData]?
    var RecordId: Int?
}



class MovementSampleData {
    var Id: Int?
    var TimeStamp: Int64?
    var X: Float?
    var Y: Float?
    var Z: Float?
}
```

I'm kinda new in swift and couldn't get this done in some time.

What's the way to approach this.

I need CreateRecordData class to send as parameter using alamofire.

Thanks

classes after adding Encodable

```
class CreateRecordData: Encodable{
    var RecordDate: String?
    var RecordType: String?
    var SubType: String?
    var Name: String?
    var AudioRecords: [AudioData]?
    var MovementRecords: [RecordMovementData]?
    var MeasurementId: Int?
    var SensorType: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case RecordDate
        case RecordType
        case SubType
        case Name
        case AudioRecords
        case MovementRecords
        case MeasurementId
        case SensorType
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(RecordDate, forKey: .RecordDate)
        try container.encode(RecordType, forKey: .RecordType)
        try container.encode(SubType, forKey: .SubType)
        try container.encode(Name, forKey: .Name)
        try container.encode(AudioRecords, forKey: .AudioRecords)
        try container.encode(MovementRecords, forKey: .MovementRecords)
        try container.encode(MeasurementId, forKey: .MeasurementId)
        try container.encode(SensorType, forKey: .SensorType)
    }
}

class RecordMovementData: Encodable{
    var FrameRate: Int?
    var JointType: String?
    var Samples: [MovementSampleData]?
    var RecordId: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case FrameRate
        case JointType
        case Samples
        case RecordId
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws{
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(FrameRate, forKey: .FrameRate)
        try container.encode(JointType, forKey: .JointType)
        try container.encode(Samples, forKey: .Samples)
        try container.encode(RecordId, forKey: .RecordId)
    }
}


class MovementSampleData: Encodable {
    var Id: Int?
    var TimeStamp: Int64?
    var X: Float?
    var Y: Float?
    var Z: Float?

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey{
        case Id
        case TimeStamp
        case X
        case Y
        case Z
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws{
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(Id, forKey: .Id)
        try container.encode(TimeStamp, forKey: .TimeStamp)
        try container.encode(X, forKey: .X)
        try container.encode(Y, forKey: .Y)
        try container.encode(Z, forKey: .Z)
    }
}
```

One more thing to mention. a don't directly use CreateRecordData as parameter. I create Dictionary with data of that class like this:

```
let recordParams: [String:Any] = [
            "RecordDate": recordData.RecordDate!,
            "RecordType": recordData.RecordType!,
            "SubType": recordData.SubType!,
            "Name": recordData.Name!,
            "AudioRecords": "",
            "MovementRecords": recordData.MovementRecords!,
            "MeasurementId": "\(recordData.MeasurementId!)",
            "SensorType": recordData.SensorType!
        ]

        AF.request("https://repac-fe-v1-webapp.azurewebsites.net/api/record",method: .post, parameters: recordParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { response in

        }
```

There might be something wrong with that as well

Comment: What kind of encoding your server expects? What have you already tried? Did you take a look at `Codable` protocol? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: @gcharita expects Json encoding. I tried Codable protocol but got error invalid type in JSON write.I'll look closer into link you sent

Comment: Please, post your `Codable` code to find out what is missing.

Comment: @gcharita I edited post, I assume I only need Encodable in my classes for what i need to do. After this I still have same Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the keys in your JSON are the same as the names of your model properties you can omit the `CodingKeys` enums from your model classes. Also, since you are not doing something custom in encoding you can completely omit the implementation of the `encode(to:)` function:

```
class AudioData: Encodable {
    // This class is missing from the posted code
}

class CreateRecordData: Encodable {
    var RecordDate: String?
    var RecordType: String?
    var SubType: String?
    var Name: String?
    var AudioRecords: [AudioData]?
    var MovementRecords: [RecordMovementData]?
    var MeasurementId: Int?
    var SensorType: String?
}

class RecordMovementData: Encodable {
    var FrameRate: Int?
    var JointType: String?
    var Samples: [MovementSampleData]?
    var RecordId: Int?
}

class MovementSampleData: Encodable {
    var Id: Int?
    var TimeStamp: Int64?
    var X: Float?
    var Y: Float?
    var Z: Float?
}
```

Making a post request with an `Encodable` object as parameters is simpler than you thought. You just call the `request` method that takes an `encoder` not an `encoding` as a parameter:

```
let recordParams = CreateRecordData() // Set the class values here

AF.request(
    "https://repac-fe-v1-webapp.azurewebsites.net/api/record",
    method: .post,
    parameters: recordParams,
    encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default,
    headers: header
).responseJSON { response in
    
}
```